# VBA Debugging: Step Into leads to Entire Program Running

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an issue where, when looking at my VBA code, I'll press F8 to "Step Into" the next line.  After about 8 steps, when I "Step Into" the line: **Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileopen)**, it takes off and runs the entire program.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub NSC_test()
'
' NSC_test Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+u
'


Const filepath As String = "H:\DEPT\Supply Management\Shared\No Standard Cost Reports\No Standard Cost Reports FYE 15\"
Dim filename As String
Dim fileopen As String
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim tempcell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet


If ActiveWorkbook.Name = "NSC Template.xlsm" Then

    'DATE OF PREVIOUS WEEK'S REPORT
    filename = Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Now()), "mm-dd-yy") 'SET THIS BACK TO -7
    filename = "NSC " & filename & ".xlsm"
    fileopen = filepath & filename
    'MsgBox fileopen 'TO CHECK IF THE FILEPATH IS CORRECT
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileopen)
    If wb Is Nothing Then MsgBox "File does not exist": Exit Sub

blah
blah
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

The code line,

```
filename = "NSC " & filename & ".xlsm"
```

... indicates to me that you are opening an macro-enabled workbook. This workbook will have event macros and/or sub procedures that are initiated on opening. This releases the debug session and the remaining code runs its course.

Comment: Interesting. I'm having the same issue on occasion, but am _not_ opening another workbook in my code. Not trying to side-track the discussion, so I'll post another question on it at some point in the near future.

Comment: after that line, filename = NSC 06-11-15.xlsm.   I'm not sure what you mean by event macros, but this should be the only macro running.  I don't have any functions which are called by this macro.

Comment: So I just debugged the code, and this time it didn't run the whole program after that line.  I'm able to debug each line at a time.  What would that indicate?